# Any python library for parallel and distributed tasks?

Tags: python, hadoop, distributed-computing

I am looking for a Python library that can distribute the tasks across a few servers. The task would be similar to what can be parallelized by the `subprocess` library in a single machine.

I know that I can setup a Hadoop system for such purposes. However Hadoop is heavy weight. In my case, I would like to use a shared network disk for data I/O, and I don't need any fancy failure recover. In MapReduce's terminology, I only need mappers, no aggregators or reducers.

Any such library in Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed
>   message passing. It is focused on real-time operation, but supports
>   scheduling as well.
>
> The execution units, called tasks, are executed concurrently on a
>   single or more worker servers using multiprocessing, Eventlet, or
>   gevent. Tasks can execute asynchronously (in the background) or
>   synchronously (wait until ready).